# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier error

Tags: javascript

Whenever I try to click on the link below I get (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier error) in the Chrome developer tools console. I can't really see anything wrong in my code, so can someone please check it and tell me what I am missing here?

```
<a href="javascript:warningMsg('Are you sure you want to delete this User? This step can't be undone!','/invoicing/users/','2','delete-user')">Delete User</a>
```

Below is the warningMsg function, unfortunately it is not even called but the .js file containing it is included in the html page with link above:

```
function warningMsg(warningMsgContent, url, id, actionType){
 alert(url+actionType+"?id="+id);
 window.location.assign(url+actionType+"/?id="+id);
}
```

Note: I tried escaping the ' in Can't by doing it can\'t but I get the same error

Thanks for your time and efforts

Comment: Try using `window.location = url+actionType+"/?id="+id;` instead

Comment: 1. Watch your quotation marks  2. Don't use inline javascript :)

Comment: @RononDex you're a runner...I have heard stories but I did not believe them to be true.

Comment: @MikeHometchko well they are, there are actually still several runners out there. Glad the SGA could help me! :P

Comment: @RononDex hands down best show of all time :)

Comment: @MikeHometchko Totally agree ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of the `'` in the word "can't" - it causes your quotes to be mismatched.

```
'Are you sure you want to delete this User? This step can't be undone!'
^                                                        ^            ^
```

To fix this you'll need to either escape the `'` in "can't" using a backslash:

```
'Are you sure you want to delete this User? This step can\'t be undone!'
```

Comment: Tried escaping the ' in Can't by can\'t but I still get the same error...any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: @JamesDonnelly he can't really wrap it in different quotes without messing up the html attribute. IMO, any answer to a question like this should include "Don't use inline js".

Answer (score 1):

You have an unescaped single quote in `can't`. It ought to be `can\t`.

```
<a href="javascript:warningMsg('Are you sure you want to delete this User? This step can\'t be undone!','/invoicing/users/','2','delete-user')">Delete User</a>
```

However, inline js (javascript in your html) should never be used (unless for quick testing purposes). Read some of these results: **[Why is inline js bad?](https://www.google.com/search?q=Why%20is%20inline%20js%20bad?)**

Instead, attach the javascript with javascript!

```
<a id="delete-user">Delete User</a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var d = document.getElementById('delete-user');
d.addEventListener('click', function() {
  warningMsg(
    "Are you sure you want to delete this User? This step can't be undone!",
    '/invoicing/users/',
    '2',
    'delete-user'
  );
});
```

**[Here's a live demo you can mess with.](http://jsbin.com/ufitUfU/1/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

try    `This step can\'t be undone!`

instead of    `This step can't be undone!`

Answer (score 0):

In `window.location.assign(url+actionType+"/?id="+id);` you will yield results similar to the following:

```
/invoicing/users/?id=2
```

Due to this: `url+actionType+"/?id="+id`.

This is, of course, in addition to the quotation escape issue everybody else has mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
<a href="javascript:warningMsg('Are you sure you want to delete this User? This step can't be undone!','/invoicing/users/','2','delete-user')">Delete User</a>
```

to:

```
<a href="javascript:warningMsg('Are you sure you want to delete this User? This step can\'t be undone!','/invoicing/users/','2','delete-user')">Delete User</a>
```

(needed to escape the `'` in the word can't)

anyway, i'd generally suggest you to use **event handlers** instead of **inline code** (onclick=...):

html:

```
<a id="btn_delete" href="#">Delete user</a>
```

javascript:

```
document.getElementById('btn_delete').addEventListener('click', function() {
    warningMsg('Are you sure you want to delete this User? This step can\'t be undone!','/invoicing/users/','2','delete-user');
});
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Good job discouraging inline js, but you suggested `onlick` rather then the preferred `addEventListener`.